# Note values in music terminology

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, musique

What are the French terms for English rhythmic values, singular and plural, such as:

sixteenth notes;
eighth notes;
quarter notes;
half notes; and,
whole notes?

Answer (score 16):

Plural mark is indicated between parenthesis

### Notes

A “note” is “*une note*”, plural “des notes”.

- [image: breve/carrée] 
  Breve: *carrée(s) n.f.*  (seldom used, I just discovered it)
- [image: semibreve/ronde]
  Semibreve (whole note): *ronde(s) n.f.*
- [image: minim/blanche] 
  Minim (half note): *blanche(s) n.f*
- [image: crotchet/noire]
  Crotchet (quarter note): *noire(s) n.f.*
- [image: quaver/croche]
  Quaver (eight note): *croche(s) n.f.*
- [image: semiquaver/double croche]
  Semiquaver (sixteenth note): *double(s) croche(s) n.f.*
- [image: demisemiquaver/triple croche] Demisemiquaver (32<sup>nd</sup> note): *triple(s) croche(s) n.f.*
- Hemidemisemiquaver (64<sup>th</sup> note): *quadruple(s) croche(s) n.f.*

And so on, *quintuple(s) croche(s)*, *sextuple(s) croche(s)*, …

In “double croche”, “triple croche”, etc., the term “croche” is often dropped if it already appeared in the same rhythm. “A dotted quaver—semiquaver”, e.g., is referred to as “une croche pointée-double”, seldom as “une croche pointée-double croche”.

### Rests

A “rest” is “*un silence*”, plural “des silences”.

- Breve rest: *double(s) pause(s) n.f.* or *bâton(s) de pause n.m.*
- [image: semibreve rest/pause]
  Semibreve rest (whole rest): *pause(s) n.f.*
- [image: minim rest/demi-pause]
  Minim rest (half rest): *demi-pause(s) n.f.*
- [image: crotchet rest/soupir]
  Crotchet rest (quarter rest): *soupir(s) n.m.*
- [image: quaver rest/demi-soupir]
  Quaver rest (eight rest): *demi-soupir(s) n.m.*
- [image: semiquaver rest/quart de soupir]
  Semiquaver rest (sixteenth rest): *quart(s) de soupir n.m.*
- [image: demisemiquaver rest/huitième de soupir]
  Demisemiquaver rest (32<sup>nd</sup> rest): *huitième(s) de soupir n.m.*
- Hemidemisemiquaver rest (64<sup>th</sup> rest): *seizième(s) de soupir n.m.*

And so on, *trente-deuxième(s) de soupir*, *soixante-quatrième(s) de soupir*, …

### Tuplets

There is no general term to designate a tuplet. Tuplet, in french, are all masculine.

- Duplet: *duolet(s) n.m.*
- Triplet: *triolet(s) n.m.*
- Quadruplet: *quartolet(s) n.m.*
- Quintuplet: *quintolet(s) n.m.*
- Sextuplet (or whatever term you prefer): *sextolet(s) n.m.*
- Septuplets: *septolet(s) n.m.*

“Triplet quavers” are “un triolet de noires”.

### Dotted notes

The dot itself is called “*point (de prolongation)*”. A “double dot” is “*un double point*”; “triple dote”, “*triple point*”.

A “dotted crotchet” is a “*noire pointée*”; “double pointed semibreve” is “*blanche double-pointée*”; “triple-dotted breve” would be “ronde triple-pointée”.

Comment: In my vision, "une note" = "un temps" = "une noire". But i don't know the english system... (While "une ronde" is worth "quatre temps"). That's what I learned in France...

Comment: “Une note” can design only a pitch or the symbol representing pitch and rhythm; in the second case, "une note” does need to last exactly “un temps” (one beat) nor “une noire”. Moreover, “une noire” does not always correspond to “un temps”; e.g., in a 2/2 or 6/8 metre. In the American system, the reference duration is the “whole note” (semibreve in Br.E.), which I guess has roots in former usage and make sense from a metre notation p.o.v. After all, a 4/4 measure lasts a semibreve, and 4/4 = 1.

Comment: It may be intresting to link the name to the symbol then, in order to avoid misunderstandings like I did reading your post.

Comment: Although I wouldn’t consider it a solid reference, the [Lilypond glossary](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/music-glossary-big-page.html) remains very practical.

Comment: @Édouard : don't want to be picky here, but you said "there is no generic term to designate a tuplet", but I found a reference to the term **nolet** both [in the Lilypond manual](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms.fr.html), and... in a fellow teacher's mouth just yesterday ;-)

Comment: I never heard of it, nor can find any reference anywhere else. It is not even in the Lilypond glossary. *“n-olet”* (pronounce the *n* as the letter) make sense to generalise to any *n* (*“17-olet”*), but “nolet”? I’d need more convincing.